# Angular ngRoute change URL but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> When i click on the href the url change but nothing seems to happens.
>   really i don't know where is the problem.

**Here the index html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp"> 
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <p><a href="#/show">addRecord</a></p>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
          .when('/show', {
            templateUrl: 'views/addRecord.html',
          });
    });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

*this is folder structure*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6nVQ.jpg)

Comment: any errors in console? `not found` ?

Comment: no errors in console neither in firefox! : (

Comment: then maybe is some styling issue `z-index` - Sajeetharan example works

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? I believe the problem is in views/addRecord.html. Is the html file mentioned in this question one level above views? In other words does the folder containing your html file also contain the views folder?

Comment: now i have this error
Cannot GET /views/addRecord.html
views -- addRecord.html
           |-- indes.html

Comment: ok so it's a get problem, the provided path is not correct

Comment: how is `index.html` situated by the `addRecord.html`(what is the folder structure)?

Comment: app folder > views folder > addRecord.html, index.html

Comment: index should be on top level, but for your example, since `index` and `addRecord` are siblings the correct path should be: `templateUrl: './addRecord.html'` on simply: `templateUrl: 'addRecord.html',`

Comment: still have 404 with both method

Comment: it should work, you sure have not misspelled something?

Comment: sure ...i'm goin' down.. . . . .   .   .         .          .

Answer (score 0):

You have nowhere mentioned ng-app

```
 <head ng-app="myApp">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/M43xX041S7CRJLuBcLNB?p=preview)**

Comment: i've missed some part of code sorry.
The ng-app is the into html tag

Comment: Did you check the demo

Comment: i think the problem is due to the hashbang mode i'm reading about that...